# Multipage Bootstrap and Google Analytics

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, google-analytics

I have sort of a problem how to use Google Analytics properly with Boostrap.

My page has 3 level deep subpages and the last subpage has it's own subdomain. In GA I see I can use max. 50 tracking codes within one service. What if I need more than that?

Comment: And why do you need 50 tracking code for your website? If you have just your own website, you can insert just one tracker (f.e. in header of all the pages).
Do you need to separate analytics data for each subpages/subdomains?

Comment: @PetrBlaha no, I just need have many views get each subpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limited to 50 properties not 50 pages. Each property can track many pages and (up to 10 million hits a month for the free version) and events.

Typically you would use the same property code on all pages on the same site so you can see all that data together (though with option to drill down).

You would only use a new property code for a new site (though your subdomain might qualify for that if you want to track it separately).

So the two questions you want to ask yourself are:

1. Do you want to be able to report on two pages together? E.g. To see that your site gets 10,000 hits and 20% are for this page and 5% are for that page. Or people start at this page and then go to that page and then on to this page. If so it should be the same analytics property.
2. Do different people need to see these page stats? And is it a problem if they do? If so put as a separate property so you can permission separately.

It sounds like these are part of the same site so I'd be veering towards tracking them together on same property.

On a different note you should set one page as the main version (with a rel canonical tag) and redirect other version to that page to avoid confusing search engines thinking you have duplicated content. Do you have a reason for having the same content on two different addresses? It can cause SEO and other problems.

Comment: So when the deepest subpage that is http://domain.com/sub1/sub2/targetPage I have at the same time at http://targetPage.domain.com then I should redirect the former to the latter so I won't have to put analytics to the latter?

Comment: Altered my answer with more info.

Comment: I still have problem with adding same code for main domain to subdomain page. It just doesn't see it or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well I don't know what to do with that comment to be honest as I can't really guess what's going on. All I can suggest is adding the Google Analytics chrome extension and seeing if the call is being made by the browser - which should show in the Console. Also I presume you're not filtering out hits in Google Analytics based on domain name?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. So here is the page in question: http://alchemist.beerhunter.me/ and the main domain http://beerhunter.me have the same GA code. Is that what I was supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, but I don't work for StackOverflow and do this in my spare time. I just used the GA Chrome extension as I advised you to do, and can see the page view being fired off to GA for both pages. So you must have a filter on GA if you are not seeing them.

Comment: Ok, I now see this. I had to turn on 'hostname'' filter to see it. Previously I couldn't see that because it showed page as `/` so basically I thought its the main domain. Now it's everything clear. Thank You for helping out :)